# Headers in Front Matter of Book

Tags: miktex, fancyhdr, emacs, front-matter

The 'List of tables' header persists across the remaining sections of the front matter (Preface, Acknowledgments, Credits, Note), only disappearing when the main matter starts. Is this an issue with Fancyheader or with the specification of items in the front matter (or something else)? Thank you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,chains,positioning}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[xindy,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries\input{./Glossary/glossary}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\lhead{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\rhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\emergencystretch 3em

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\hyphenation{
  \@@input ./Hyphenation/hyphenation.txt
}
\makeatother

\frontmatter
\author{}
\date{}
\title{}
\maketitle
\include{./TeX_files/dedication}
\tableofcontents\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\include{./TeX_files/preface}
\include{./TeX_files/acknowledgements}
\include{./TeX_files/credits}
\include{./TeX_files/note}

\mainmatter
\include{./TeX_files/chapter01}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter02}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter03}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter04}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter05}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter06}
\include{./TeX_files/chapter07}

\backmatter
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{../../../BibTeX/library}
\setglossarystyle{list}
\glsaddall
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossary}
\printglossary
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Comment: Please make sure your example is self contained, you are including stuff we do not have access to and which are probably not relevant to your question

Comment: As the headers come from `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` it probably means that the file you include (`/TeX_files/preface`) doesn't generate any marks. For example because it has no `\chapter` or `\section` command, or only `\chapter*`. Maybe `\chaptermark{Preface}` will cure this, or even `\chaptermark{}` for an empty one.

Comment: Thanks Pieter. Using \chaptermark{} gives me 'Chapter 0', and using \chaptermark{Preface} gives me 'Chapter 0. Preface'. Is there any way I can have just 'Preface' in the header?